# How to factor this expression in the fireman's problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm trying to solve the fireman's optimization problem. It boils down to factoring the following expression:

$2\left ( q + \frac{pq}{a} \right )\cdot \left ( -\frac{pq}{a^2} \right ) + 2(p+a)$

I have spent around 5 pages of paper trying to solve this but to no avail. According to the solution you can factor out $2(p+a)$, but how? This is *not* homework by the way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+2%5Cleft+(+q+%2B+%5Cfrac%7Bpq%7D%7Ba%7D+%5Cright+)%5Ccdot+%5Cleft+(+-%5Cfrac%7Bpq%7D%7Ba%5E2%7D+%5Cright+)+%2B+2(p%2Ba)) agrees.

Comment: What do $a,p,q$ represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $q+\frac{pq}{a}=\frac{q}{a}(a+p)$, your expression factorises to $$2(p+a)\left(\frac{q}{a}\frac{-pq}{a^2}+1\right)=2(p+a)(1-pq^2/a^3).$$

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with fractions, it helps to clear denominators.

Let
$$
t=2\left ( q + \frac{pq}{a} \right )\cdot \left ( -\frac{pq}{a^2} \right ) + 2(p+a)
$$
Then
$$
a^3t=
2\left ( aq + {pq} \right )\cdot \left ( -{pq} \right ) + 2(p+a)a^3
$$
Now just notice
$$
(aq+pq)=(a+p)q=(p+a)q
$$